# Origin and meaning of "rackers"

Tags: etymology

I have read that Don Armado is one of those *rackers of orthography* who distort the written language when they convert it into speech. What is the origin of the word *rackers*? What does it mean?

> Holofeners: "*He draweth out the thread of his verbosity finer than the
>   staple of his argument [...] such **rackers of orthography**, as to speak
>   dout, fine, when he should said doubt; [...].*"

Comment: First of all, it's the **spoken** language that gets converted into writing, not the other way around. Second, written English is already as distorted as it's possible to get and still use an alphabetic system. So I doubt there is any substance to the accusation. In any event, quotations that use _-eth_ on 3SgPres verbs are rarely useful for explicating modern English.

Comment: Can you give a link to more context? It's really hard to tell what's going on here. ('Racker' sounds like a word but really doesn't mean anything...someone who racks? that just sounds weird.) It might be archaic and so in the OED.

Comment: @Mitch - See here http://books.google.it/books?id=zArpAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA326&lpg=PA326&dq=rackers+of+orthography&source=bl&ots=WpNeAEHZln&sig=ZIg6G4W7QgKCPt2tczlXIZ0mq2I&hl=it&sa=X&ei=-lKET_XYGaKC4gSLxtGuBw&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=rackers%20of%20orthography&f=false

Comment: Why didn't you give the context or quote the original Shakespeare or give a link to it? (the google books link didn't work for me, so I googled for it). It's common courtesy to do the research work first and then give links with explanation of where you got it from, when composing your question to begin with.

Comment: @JohnLawler: this site isn't just for modern English; asking for an explanation of a line of Shakespeare is just as on-topic as asking to 'explicate'a newspaper editorial. (Admittedly, there are other reasons to be uneasy about this question.)

Comment: @Mitch - Please see here: http://www.rhymezone.com/r/gwic.cgi?Path=shakespeare/comedies/loveslabourslost/v_i//&Word=honorificabilitudinitatibus:+thou+art+easier - I did not thought that the link I have pointed to did not function from other countries.

Comment: Maybe a link is good for those who are curious, but I should have encouraged giving a better quote, with the explicit reference (e.g. Love's Labour Lost, Act V, Sc ?? etc, etc).

Comment: @Mitch - Changing Literacies for Changing Time (An Historical Perspective on the Future of Reading ...), James W. Hoffman, Yetta M. Goodman - Pag. 163.

Comment: @JohnLawler: yes, literally you are right, but the original Shakespeare really is about converting writing into speech.

Comment: @TimLymington: I disagree. Explicating Shakespeare is off-topic to me. Note that Holofeners's quoted speech there includes, for example *"...he clepeth a calf, cauf; half, hauf; neighbour vocatur nebor; neigh abbreviated ne. This is abhominable - which he would call abbominable: it insinuateth me of insanie: anne intelligis..."* I do not think this is suitable material to be asking about on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: How can it not be on topic?

Comment: @Carlo_R.: you should have put such references in your original post. That would have helped it not be closed (except for FumbleFinger's vote which, though I disagree with it, is reasonable).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in what sense is Shakespeare not 'English Language'? The difference between *abhominable* and *abominable* would make a fine question. *Vocatur* could be queried, but then so could *exempli gratia*.  Anyway, this has been discussed on meta, and any form of English is on-topic, though translations are not.  And if you think Shakespeare is off-topic for translation, I shall vote to close all the New York Times questions: Maureen Dowd's language is considerably more foreign than Shakespeare's.

Comment: @Mitch - I am bewildered seeing this question closed. I think that this event questioning the fame of ELU as a serious site on English language. I am particularly surpraise for John Lawler e FumbleFinger's votes. It is incredible!

Comment: @Mitch,Carlo_R,TimLymington: I speak for myself only. Others who voted to close may have their own perspectives. I don't want to see ELU preoccupied with analysing linguistic forms that were essentially "theatrical" over four centuries ago, and bear only passing resemblance to our current forms. That's Lit Crit, or at best historical linguistics. I don't object to such matters being introduced as relevant factors in Answers or Comments, but I don't endorse Questions where such matters are obviously the *only* issues in play.

Comment: @Carlo_R: I just don't understand why you ask many of the questions you do here. I don't wish to seem disrespectful, but you clearly don't have great fluency in modern English usage. Surely it would make more sense for you to use ELU as a tool to address that shortcoming? I'm only one person with one vote here, so it's obviously not just me causing the majority of your questions to be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'd spelt *Holofernes* right, it would have been easier to pick up that this is from Shakespeare.  Holofernes, in *Love's Labour Lost*, is a pompous, self-satisfied schoolmaster, who takes it on himself to criticise other people's English. (Thank goodness we have none such on this site.) He means that Don Armado is torturing the language when he pronounces *doubt* 'dout', and *debt*, 'det'.  Yes, these are the modern pronunciations. Even in the sixteenth century they were common; but it is possible, if you are a small-minded pedant with less education than you think, to say they are wrong, based on etymology.  It would be a mistake to think Holofernes is meant as a serious character; much more so to rely on his views on English.

Comment: Thank you Jasper.  It was in fact a typo, but it would have looked embarrassingly as if I were hoist with my own petard.

Answer (score 5):

I would hazard a guess that it has something to do with the rack. NOAD defines rack (v.) as to "cause extreme physical or mental pain to; subject to extreme stress," which definition is obviously based on its subsidiary one, to "torture (someone) on the rack," which was "an instrument of torture consisting of a frame on which the victim was stretched by turning rollers to which the wrists and ankles were tied."

Comment: M-W seems to confirm—http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/racker